# K2 Blackpearl what is a definition for Folio

Tags: k2

I am new to K2 Blackpearl. I have searched the web for a description of what a  Folio is. Can someone please explain what a Folio is in K2 Blackpearl?

Answer (score 2):

Folio is a process level property which can be used to differentiate various instances of a workflow. Lets consider a scenario - you have a K2 Approval workflow for Bill Request of different markets. 
We can set Process folio as : " "Market" - Bill Request" which will help the end user to distinguish it . We have a unique Process ID for every workflow but that is of no use for an end user. 
Process Folio can be set either when it is triggered from smart forms or Web Services and in the workflow using Data Event or Server code Event.

Comment: I like to think of it as being like a "Subject" line for a process instance

Comment: The comment by @s3raph86 should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think of a Folio is as the subject line for a process

Answer (score 0):

Folio is a Title for each process instance. Try to keep your folio unique for each instance in for a particular process. I normally add ID or Process Originator name to folio which helpful when you need to troubleshoot any instance as you folio name is informative. Below is an example,

If I have a workflow to Approve Documents.
*Process Name:* DocumentSignOff
*Folio:* DocumentSignOff-[ProcessInstanceID]-[Originator]
*i.e.* DocumentSignOff-1254-JognDoe

Answer (score 0):

Basically in K2, a folio is a description that tags one WF task submitted from the other. The best way to create a folio, is to ensure that, every task submitted gets to be concatenated to a Process InstanceID. 
For instance: Cash Advance for Wallace Cole - 17893
Appending process Instance ID to every task submitted is one of the best ways to track task submitted,using the Process Instance ID or in short ProcID.